# Asp.NetCore Middleware Authorization

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an AspNetCore web API that I wish to secure with IdentityServer4. I have successfully implemented IdentityServer4, and have no trouble securing methods **in MVC controllers** using the `[Authorize]` attribute.

I cannot figure out how to enforce security with **custom (non-MVC) middleware**, however. For example, in my Startup.cs, I have:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
  // I want to require an authenticated user here
  using (var writer = new StreamWriter(context.Response.Body))
  {
    await writer.WriteAsync(string.Format("Welcome to the jungle, {0}", context.User.Identity.Name);
  }
});
```

I could take a brute-force approach, but clearly the `app.UseIdentityServer();` is geared to handle that heavily lifting, so I don't want to re-invent the wheel here.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to just put `app.UseIdentityServer()` before the custom owin middleware ,all the middleware will be called in the sequential order they are written in the code. Hence any unauthorized users will be filter out and redirected even before they reach your custom middleware.

Comment: I've done that, but users are NOT prompted to log in simply by placing `app.UseIdentityServer()`. This makes sense, as some MVC methods may not be tagged with the `[Authorize]` attribute, implying anonymous access should be allowed.